# How to highlight dates in a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to select dates (note: all dates, not just specific dates) in a paragraph using (I'm assuming) jQuery/Javascript.

To give an example, the website gets a bunch of text from a database, and in that text is included a date in the following format: (DD/MM/YYYY). I just want to highlight everytime that comes up, but I'm not sure how because sometimes the date can be 02/09/2014 or 13/10/2014, so I can't just search for a certain date and highlight it.

Any help is appreciated :) Thanks!

Comment: You might want to consider using [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I'm really new to web development and I haven't come across this yet. I will be looking into this in that case :D

Comment: While looking at it, in your case you'll probably want to use the digit character `\d` (equivalent to any digit from 0 to 9). You might also want to quantify it: `\d{1,2}` (require this character to appear 1 to 2 times). Good luck with getting it to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you may be looking for is something like this.   Here is a [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fzpzdqh3/)

```
  $("div").html($("div").html().replace(/(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})/gi, "<span style='background-color:yellow;'>$1</span>"));
```

Here is the same code above only on different lines for easier reading.

```
    $("div")
   .html( 
      $("div")
        .html()
         .replace(/(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})/gi, 
          "<span style='background-color:yellow;'>$1</span>"
       )
   );
```

First we group the regEx with a left and right parentheses.   This is now able to be referenced  as parameter $1.  We then look for the pattern we are seeking (do not forgot to add the **gi** at the end so that you look for all occurrences, not just the first one.

We then replace our find with a span tag so that we can style the contents, in this case a yellow background and we still want the date we found so we add in the $1 to put the date inside the span tags.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank u so much, it worked. The example was really well written too. Tahnks a bunch man :D!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a super basic regex that will find 'datelike' number series:

\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}

Try it out here: http://regexhero.net/tester/

Using some text like "This is some text for the regex hero on 9/2/2014. I think for the most part it will work for what you are looking for on 9/3/2014."

In fact, here's some javascript to play with (using jquery):

http://jsfiddle.net/5z7bz4zm/2/

```
<div>
    This is some text for the regex hero on 9/2/2014. I think for the most part it will work for what you are looking for on 9/3/2014.
</div>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("div").text($("div").text().replace(/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/, "<span>caught ya</span>"));
});
```